# onHover effect doesn't work on TextButton nor InkWell

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am developing a Flutter website. I have some links that I want to behave as a normal link: with a different color when the user hovers over them. However, I can't manage to make the color change.

I have tried using a TextButton with the `onHover` property. I have also tried with an Inkwell `onHover` property and `hoverColor`. I have wrapped the InkWell with Material and my `onTap` function is defined. I have also tried by wrapping this on an AnimatedContainer, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code.

```
TextStyle? bodyTextStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall;

InkWell(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: Text(
    "data policy",
    style: bodyTextStyle,
  ),
  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
    Navigation(context).routes["data policy"]),
  onHover: (isHovering) {
    setState(() {
      bodyTextStyle = isHovering
          ? bodyTextStyle?.copyWith(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline)
          : bodyTextStyle;
    });
  },
),
```

I prefer using InkWell rather than TextButton in order to get rid of the shadow around the text that TextButton creates.

Comment: Can you simplify the widget with necessary data, like here `linkTextStyle` `TextRenderer`... are unknown

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this snippet, `hoverColor` from InkWell can overlap.

```dart
InkWell(
  child: SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Text(
        "Text",
        style: linkTextStyle,
      )),
  onTap: () {},
  hoverColor: Colors.transparent, //button splash color
  onHover: (isHovering) {
    linkTextStyle = isHovering
        ? TextStyle(color: Colors.red)
        : TextStyle(color: Colors.cyanAccent);
    setState(() {});
  },
),
```

Also You can check `MouseRegion`, `elevation` on buttonStyle.